# Sum values per month from array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, charts, sum

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var json = [ { day: '01-01-2018', hour: '00:00', value: '121' }, { day: '01-02-2018', hour: '05:24', value: '131' }, { day: '26-01-2018', hour: '00:07', value: '101' }, { day: '16-02-2018', hour: '08:02', value: '56' }, { day: '20-02-2018', hour: '12:02', value: '123' }, { day: '24-03-2018', hour: '10:11', value: '45' }];
```

I would like to change format of date from DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD and then sum values per month to create a chart.

My attempt:

```
var mapDateVolume = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
        {
            var allDate = json[i].day;
            var oneVolume = json[i].value;
            var splitedDate = allDate.split("-");
            var newOrderY = splitedDate[2] + "-" 
            var newOrderM = splitedDate[1] + "-";
            var newOrderD = splitedDate[0];
            var newOrderAllDate = newOrderY + newOrderM + newOrderD;  

            var newOrder = {};
            newOrder[newOrderAllDate] = oneVolume;
            mapDateVolume.push(newOrder);

        }

var result = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < mapDateVolume.length; i++){

            var key = Object.keys(mapDateVolume)[i].split("-")[0] + "/";
            key += Object.keys(mapDateVolume)[i].split("-")[1];
            var value = Object.values(mapDateVolume)[i];
            var oldValue = Object.keys(result)[i] != null ? Object.keys(result)[i] : 0;

            var newResult = {};
            newResult[key] = value;
            result.push(newResult);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

            xAxis.push(Object.keys(result)[i]);
            yAxis.push(Object.values(result)[i]);

        }
```

I use Chart.js and it works fine with days:

```
 for ( var i = 0; i < jsonAll.length; i++ )
 {

   xAxis.push(json[i].day+'-'+json[i].hour);
   yAxis.push(json[i].value);

 }
```

I know that something is wrong with this sum because I see only an empty chart. Unfortunately, I have little experience with JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all lets format whole collection (data array).

**We need to:**

1. Date format: *DD-MM-YYYY* to *YYYY-MM-DD*.
2. *Value property* is a **string** type we need it as **number**.

Simple with `Array#Map`:

```
const collection = data.map(x => ({ ...x, day: x.day.split("-").reverse().join("-"), value: Number(x.value)}));
```

Next thing is to use again `Array#Map` to replace *day property* to *Month*.

```
const mapDayToMonth = collection.map(x => ({...x, day: new Date(x.day).getMonth()}));
```

> The `getMonth()` method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time. So, 0 is *January*, 1 is *February* ...etc

Last step `Array#Reduce` to sum value per **Month**:

```
const sumPerMonth = mapDayToMonth.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.day] = acc[cur.day] + cur.value || cur.value;
  return acc;
}, {})
```

Full example **JSFiddle**:

```js
const data = [ { day: '01-01-2018', hour: '00:00', value: '121' }, { day: '01-02-2018', hour: '05:24', value: '131' }, { day: '26-01-2018', hour: '00:07', value: '101' }, { day: '16-02-2018', hour: '08:02', value: '56' }, { day: '20-02-2018', hour: '12:02', value: '123' }, { day: '24-03-2018', hour: '10:11', value: '45' }];

    const collection = data.map(x => ({ ...x, day: x.day.split("-").reverse().join("-"), value: Number(x.value)}));

    console.log(collection);

    const mapDayToMonth = collection.map(x => ({...x, day: new Date(x.day).getMonth()}));

    console.log(mapDayToMonth);

    const sumPerMonth = mapDayToMonth.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc[cur.day] = acc[cur.day] + cur.value || cur.value; // increment or initialize to cur.value
      return acc;
    }, {})

    console.log(sumPerMonth)
```

Useful links:

[Array Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

[Number Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

[Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: I ran your code and it changes date format very well. You use Number and at the end I get only one number of sum. I need something like sum of every month to present it on the chart: X-axis (month), Y-axis (sum of this month).

Comment: give me a second to fix.

Comment: @Michael Angelo Turtle Updated

Comment: Please @Michael Angelo Turtle tell me does it works and accept answer if everything is fine. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question. My example was with dates from the same year. Having dates from different years, how to code, to sum up values for each year month separately? For example to have a chart with: Jan 2017: 720, ... Dec 2017: 876, Jan 2018: 869, ... Dec 2018: 435.

Comment: @MichaelAngeloTurtle Yes, you can do that in that way. Btw take a look at this lib http://momentjs.com maybe can help to work with dates in combination with reduce. ;) Good luck!

Comment: @RobG i mean VAR JSON. That variable is an Array as u can see in a question.

Comment: @RobG I'm gonna fix question instead `var json` to `const data`. It's much better.

Comment: Fine, but in parsing the string and using *getMonth* you are changing between local and UTC time zones. For users west of Greenwich, `new Date('2018-01-01').getMonth()` returns 11, not 0. I suggest that rather than parse the string to create another string to be parsed by the built-in parser, give the values directly to the Date constructor (remembering to subtract 1 from the month). E.g. `new Date(...'24-03-2018'.split(/\D/).reverse().map((v, i)=>v-i%2))`.

Comment: That is one of the best explained answers that i came across . Cheers @MarkoSavic great job.