# how do you add multiple numbers from an object that comes from a database?

Tags: javascript

code:

```
  const _id = req.body.idLights;

      Feed.findById(_id, (err, fountItemsFeed) => {
        Feed.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { lights: fountItemsFeed.lights }, (err, foundItemsLights) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            foundItemsLights.lights = fountItemsFeed.lights + 1;
            foundItemsLights.save();  
          }
        });

        User.findByIdAndUpdate(
          req.user.id,
          { lights: fountItemsFeed.lights },
          (err, foundItemsLights_Stats) => {
            Feed.find({id: fountItemsFeed.id}, (err, result) => {
              result.forEach((feed) => {
                console.log(feed)
          })
          // foundItemsLights_Stats.save();
            });
            res.redirect("/#" + _id);
          }
        );
      });
});
```

code from DB: **in console**

```
{
 _id: 612bfc5846f57f411406a024,
 comm: [],
 id: '6128b92bd5a7192e30100110',
 profile_name: 'Iuliaan ' ,
 lights: 28,
 __v: 0
}
{
 _id: 612bfc9a46f57f411406a03d,
 comm: [],
 id: '6128b92bd5a7192e30100110',
 profile_name: 'Iuliaan ' ,
 lights: 8,
 __v: 0
}
{
 _id: 612bfcce46f57f411406a048,
 comm: [],
 id: '6128b92bd5a7192e30100110',
 profile_name: 'Iuliaan ' ,
 lights: 14,
 __v: 0
}
```

and i put instead console.log(feed) i put (feed.lights) i see in console:

```
28
8
14
```

how add all numbers dynamics? i want all numbers add " 28 + 8 + 14 = 50 "
how can i do in javascript to gather all those numbers dynamically? I need a quick fix. Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum values per month from array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783238/sum-values-per-month-from-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `reducer` on your array in this way:

```js
let result = [{
 _id: "612bfc5846f57f411406a024",
 comm: [],
 id: '6128b92bd5a7192e30100110',
 profile_name: 'Iuliaan ' ,
 lights: 28,
 __v: 0
},
{
 _id: "612bfc9a46f57f411406a03d",
 comm: [],
 id: '6128b92bd5a7192e30100110',
 profile_name: 'Iuliaan ' ,
 lights: 8,
 __v: 0
},
{
 _id: "612bfcce46f57f411406a048",
 comm: [],
 id: '6128b92bd5a7192e30100110',
 profile_name: 'Iuliaan ' ,
 lights: 14,
 __v: 0
}];

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.lights;

console.log(result.reduce(reducer, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using async/await

```
const feed = await Feed.findById(_id)
let lightsNumber = feed.reduce((a, b) => a.lights + b.lights)
```